# Why do we need to use one `var` to define many variables?

Tags: javascript

I defined some variables in Javascript:

```
var aaa = "aaa";
var bbb = "bbb";
var ccc = "ccc";
```

But my friend says it should be better to define them as:

```
var aaa = "aaa",
    bbb = "bbb",
    ccc = "ccc";
```

Because JsLint will report errors on my code.

I'm not sure why we should do it as the second one, since I found my version is better to view if the value is very big, like:

```
var aaa = {
             some1 : 111,
             some2 : 222
          };
var bbb = {
             some1 : 111,
             some2 : 222
          };
```

Comment: Think this is a matter of preference and the standards in your company. Personally I would always go for the former, because you know that for every `var`, there is something new there.

Comment: _"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_
As far as I know, there's technically no difference between your first 2 examples.

Comment: Here you have an article supporting this approach. 


  http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/

Comment: "JsLine will report errors on my code" - Any chance you're more specific about that? I don't even know what JsLine is (do you mean JSLint?)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, yes, it's JSLint

Comment: @Hoijof, we should not miss the link you provided!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript there is no block scope, only function level scope. So, if you use multiple `var` statements, the developers who are coming from other languages might not feel the difference. For example,

```
var numbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    numbers.push(i);
}
```

If you are familiar with C, C++ or JAVA, you might think that the `i` is not available outside the `for` loop. But it is, because of the reason mentioned in the first line.

So, to avoid the confusion, JSLint encourages you to use only one `var` statement per function, and that too should be the first line of that function.

Quoting from the [jslint's documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#scope),

> In many languages, a block introduces a scope. Variables introduced in a block are not visible outside of the block.
>
> In JavaScript, blocks do not introduce a scope. There is only function-scope. A variable introduced anywhere in a function is visible everywhere in the function. JavaScript's blocks confuse experienced programmers and lead to errors because the familiar syntax makes a false promise.
>
> JSLint expects blocks with `function`, `if`, `switch`, `while`, `for`, `do`, and `try` statements and nowhere else.
>
> In languages with block scope, it is usually recommended that variables be declared at the site of first use. But because JavaScript does not have block scope, *it is wiser to declare all of a function's variables at the top of the function. It is recommended that a single var statement be used per function.* This can be declined with the `vars` option.

Comment: Just don't forget that JSLint combines two possibly related but actually entirely different features: protect programmers from potential bugs and enforce Douglas Crockford preferences about code formatting. The latter is useful to Mr. Crockford but your mileage may vary.